# Marks Date on calender Tapku

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray, tapku

I have below api. I need to mark the days that i have here. But the formate of the library date is like this:

```
@"2013-08-12 00:00:00 +0000"
```

How can I add my api below like this date formate?

```
{
      "year": "2013",
      "month": "08",
      "calendarDays":  [ "17", "24"  ]
}
```

I have done something like this, but it didn't worked for me.

```
//calElem year --> year
//[calElem month] --> month
//self.CalenderDaysArray -->calendarDays


for(int i=0; i<[self.CalenderDaysArray count]; i++){

      self.CalenderDaysArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@ 00:00:00 +0000",[calElem year],[calElem month],[self.CalenderDaysArray objectAtIndex:i], nil]];

}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem with below code:

```
  NSMutableArray *datearray=[NSMutableArray array];
            NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

            NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            NSArray *myStringArr=[self.CalenderDays objectAtIndex:0];

            for(int i=0; i<myStringArr.count; i++){

                    todayComponents.year = [[calElem year]intValue];
                    todayComponents.month = [[calElem month] intValue];
                    todayComponents.day = [[myStringArr objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
                    todayComponents.hour = 00;
                    todayComponents.minute = 00;
                    todayComponents.second= 00;
                    NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:todayComponents];
                    [datearray addObject:[self getdateCalendar:today]];


            }
```